# Using R to explore Google Analytics data specifically looking for user ID

Tags: r, csv, google-analytics-api

I saw questions similar like that but no answers yet. Here I am going to ask again.

I am working on export data from GA using R and GA-R library. I am working well on that part. But I couldn't find anything that represent user ID or Client ID in the library. So to speak, I couldn't find any variable let me sort data by different users.

Basically I am asking, which variable could I use for User ID or Client ID in GA-R-Library. So I could easily sort user level data as a csv file.

Please answer that if you have any idea!
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: user ID needs a custom implementation, client ID could be used as a proxy, but even for that you will need to send it to a custom dimension first.

Comment: You cant really you are looking for something like a primary key there isn't one.  Usier id and cid are values used in the background by google analytics for processing.  They aren't something that you can request out of the API.

Comment: As mentioned above User Id and Client Id are not available [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets). The link provided has the complete list of available dimensions and metrics.